# Full text search with inner join very slow

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that executes very slowly:

```
SELECT Id FROM
    (
        SELECT  E.MessageId
        FROM    [MessageEnvelopes] AS E INNER JOIN
                [Folders] AS F ON F.Id = E.FolderId
        WHERE   F.MailboxId = 1
    ) AS SUB1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  M.Id
        FROM    [Messages] AS M 
        WHERE   CONTAINS(M.*, '"my*" AND "search*"')
    ) AS SUB2
    ON SUB1.MessageId = SUB2.Id
```

Basically, this joins a message selection query (SUB1) with a fulltext search (SUB2). The subqueries have been separated for clarity (the same behaviour occurs when the subqueries are joined together). This query takes about 15 seconds, while both subqueries return instantly when executed separately.

The tables involved are small (max. 2000 rows). There are indexes on all foreign keys. The execution plan shows no bottlenecks. I have no idea why this query would be running so slow.

Comment: have you tried using CONTAINSTABLE() ? This should normally perform better than CONTAINS()

Comment: @Greco, no the same thing happens.

Comment: @Carvellis, did you ever resolve this problem? I'm having the same thing now.

Comment: @SimonGreen sorry but I can't remember, I've not worked on this in many years.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the query plan shows that the three tables are joined together before the FullTextMatch is evaluated. If you execute the queries separately you force the plan to evaluate the FullTextMatch against Messages before the join. That might be good or bad for you depending on how much data is in the tables and how "selective" the where clause is against MailboxId. If you see that you have a lot better performance with the queries separated you can use two table variable to store the intermediary result and query the variables for the joined output.

Comment: Even so, the table holds 2000 records. There must be something else going on for a query to take 15 seconds on such a small table.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys... the issue was that the statistics were out of date, and the execution plan was performing a nested loop join, meaning that it was hitting the FT index once for each row returned from the other side of the join. After updating the statistics, the plan used a hash join, meaning that it performed a single hit to the FT index, built a hastable from it and matched on that instead.